# Booting Stuck at "Loading Initial Ram Disk..."

Tags: 12.10, boot, uefi

I just installed Ubuntu on my system. My system have UEFI. No secure boot enabled. I ran the installation DVD in EFI mode. After installation, everything works fine. But if I update the kernel or do some other changes like installing graphics drivers, the boot screen gets stuck. The OS won't load.

When checking the BIOS boot menu, I found two Ubuntu EFI entries. One of them work and the other doesn't. Whats really going on in my system? Please help!

PS : I use Ubuntu 12.10 64bit version.

Comment: Please indicate your Boot-Info URL ( https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info ), it will help understand your EFI entries.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your updated kernel is causing the problems. Not sure how, but you can purge it and use your older kernel.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way that should work for the kernel.

Find a boot option that you can boot into.

Download and install a program called `grub customiser`. After a bit a bit of googleing I found these commands to install it.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

After that is installed, open it and type in your sudoer password.
Next, go into general settings and change the default to either the kernel you had just booted into or to previously booted entry. (You can check which kernel you are using by typing "uname -a" into a terminal.) This should change it default to the working kernel.

**If you want to purge the other kernels:**

After getting changing the boot preference, you should know which kernel you are using. during this procedure make sure that you DON'T DELETE the working kernel.

In a a terminal type:

```
sudo nautilus
```

This will open a nautilus window with sudoer privileges. Head into the kernel directories in `/boot` and in `/usr/src` and delete the old kernels. (Move them if you want to keep them) If I am correct, the system won't know where they are and grub will only recognise the working kernel. (If not, then delete them in grub customiser.)

Hope this helps!